# Adding a prefix to WooCommerce archive loop and product page images (for Cloudflare image resizing)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cloudflare

On Wordpress/WooCommerce am using Cloudflare business account for image resizing and conversion and have wrote some code that adds a prefix to the image paths (stored by that plugin) that is required for the resizing and conversion of images.

Check this link:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/url-format

My code for the first plugin I did this for:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'prod_logo_cloudflare_image_resize' ) ) {
  function prod_logo_cloudflare_image_resize( $image, $thumbnail_id ) {
    $src   = '/cdn-cgi/image/fit=scale-down,width=75,format=auto,quaity=75/' . wp_get_attachment_image_url( $thumbnail_id );
    $image = '<img src="' . $src . '"/>';

    return $image;
  }

  add_filter( 'logo_image_size_single_product', 'prod_logo_cloudflare_image_resize', 10, 2 );
}
```

Curious if anyone has any experience with this or knows how to accomplish via functions.php file.

Note that I am trying to avoid creating a Worker to resize/convert all my images.

EDIT: Note that I am trying to do this with the product loop (category pages, search, related products).

Comment: the code is working?

Comment: Yeah this works for another plugins image but not still trying to figure out the right hook to use for the archive loop (product categories).